# How can I insert new nodes in Binary search tree?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to insert into a BST N times, and I have to ask the user to enter the data inside the `insert` function. This is my code. I tried to print the tree using preorder method but it's printing only the last input. I have to use ID as a key, and print using PreOrder all the data Salary and ID.

```cpp
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    struct Node{

        int EmployeeID;
        float Salary;
        struct Node* left;
        struct Node* right;
    };

    struct Node* insert(struct Node* root,int ID, float Salary){



        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &ID);

        printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
        scanf("%f", &Salary);

        if(root == NULL){

            root = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            root->EmployeeID = ID;
            root->Salary = Salary;
            root->left=root->right= NULL;
        }

        else if(ID < root->EmployeeID)
            root->left = insert(root->left, ID, Salary);
        else
            root->right = insert(root->right, ID, Salary);

    return root;

    };

    void PrePrint(struct Node* root){

        if(root == NULL)
            return;

        printf("%d   %.2f", root->EmployeeID, root->Salary);
        PrePrint(root->left);
        PrePrint(root->right);

        return;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int N, i;
        struct Node* root;
        int ID;
        int Sal;
        root = NULL;

        printf("How many Employee you would like to enter? \n");
        scanf("%d", &N);

        for(i=0; i<N; i++){

            root = insert(root, ID, Sal);
            printf("\n");

        }
            PrePrint(root);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first statement `root = NULL;` in your insert function.

As far as the insert function is concerned, you can modify it to:

```cpp
struct Node* insert(struct Node* root, int ID, float Salary){
        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &ID);

        printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
        scanf("%f", &Salary);

        struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->EmployeeID = ID;
        newNode->Salary = Salary;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;

        struct Node* cp_of_root = root;
        if(root==NULL)
             return newNode;
        struct Node* parent = NULL;
        while(root!=NULL){
             parent = root;
             if (newNode->val > root->val)
                  root = root->right;
             else
                  root = root->left;
        }
        if(newNode->val > parent->val)
              parent->right = newNode;
        else
              parent->left = newNode;
        return cp_of_root;

}
```

I hope this code clears up your doubt.

Comment: I removed it from the function,  but it still won't print :)

Comment: Change `root->left=root->right=NULL` to two different statements `root->left = NULL; root->right = NULL`.

Comment: Also, rather than asking for ID and salary in the insert function, ask that in the main function itself.

Comment: I would love to ask in the main :) but this is what they asked me to do :(

Comment: Doesn't this then require entering same values till one reaches a leaf node?
In this case, what you can rather do is ask the user to enter the value, then instead of calling the function recursively, just create a copy of the root, and traverse the BST till you reach a leaf node. Insert the new node there, and now return the root (remember you created its copy)

Comment: @it'sM I tested out your code. Your print logic is correct. Insertion logic is correct to some extent. Consider the case when the root has ID 4, and you need to insert ID=2. So when the code asks you to enter ID, you enter 2. Then the code compares the value of 2 and 4, and decides it has to insert value to the left of the root. It calls the insert function again, and asks you to enter ID. Now, you must enter the same ID as before, because the insertion has not taken place yet.

Comment: can you please code what you suggested?  i couldn't understand what do you mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

to keep the scanf in the insert function you want to make a flag to know if it's your first time initializing the variables(id and salary) or you already have values and don't want to scanf again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node{

    int EmployeeID;
    float Salary;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};

struct Node* insert(struct Node* root,int ID, float Salary){
    if(ID==-1 && Salary==-1)
    {
        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &ID);

        printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
        scanf("%f", &Salary);

    }
    if(root == NULL){

        root = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        root->EmployeeID = ID;
        root->Salary = Salary;
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right= NULL;
    }

    else if(ID < root->EmployeeID)
        root->left = insert(root->left, ID, Salary);
    else
        root->right = insert(root->right, ID, Salary);

return root;

};

void PrePrint(struct Node* root){

    if(root == NULL)
        return;

    printf("%d   %.2f\n", root->EmployeeID, root->Salary);
    PrePrint(root->left);
    PrePrint(root->right);

return;
}
int main()
{
    int N, i;
    struct Node* root;
    int ID;
    float Salary;
    root = NULL;

    printf("How many Employee you would like to enter? \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        root = insert(root, ID=-1, Salary=-1);
        printf("\n");

    }
        PrePrint(root);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for doing that, but they asked me to fill ID and Salary in the insertion function not in the main :/

Comment: i will fix that

Comment: if the salary and and the id is equal to -1 that mean till now i did't scanf from the user the values so i make scanf else we use the values in the variables id and salary